# Titel ist Jacke wie Hose

Tags: etymology

**Das ist mir [Jacke wie Hose](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jacke)**, ''das ist mir einerlei; gleich'' Dem gleichen Muster folgt *gehupft wie gesprungen*.

Es handelt sich doch nicht etwa um [Jacque](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jacque) und [José](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9), welche ich tatsächlich kaum unterscheiden kann? Nur mit Hilfe modernster Nachrichtentechnik und sprachkundiger Nachhilfe kann ich diese noch als Französischen "Jacob" und Spanischen "Joseph" entziffern.

Die geläufige Erklärung:

> ... bezieht sich darauf, dass man in der Neuzeit dazu überging, Jacke und Hose aus dem gleichen Stoff zu schneidern ...

Wo ist da der Witz, der dem Spruch weitere Beliebtheit zuteilt?

Idiom. "das gleiche in Grün" *könnte wohl auch auf Stoff hindeuten.*

Übrigens wird tatsächlich [Jacke](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jacke) über eine verallgemeinerte Bezeichnung der Bauern scheinbar vom Personennamen abgeleitet. Dabei handelt es sich doch offenbar um übelsten Rassismus, nicht wahr?

Comment: Wird dies im [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Jacke+wie+Hose+sein&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou) behandelt?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it misses the necessary quality

Comment: Was genau ist hier die Frage? Die Bedeutung der Redewendung hast du bereits erklärt. Ob du mit dieser Erklärung einverstanden bist, hat keinen Einfluss auf ihre Richtigkeit.

Comment: @vectory Ich habe deinen letzten Kommentar gelöscht, weil er klar gegen den Code of Conduct dieser Seite verstößt. Bitte bedenke, dass hinter jedem Account hier ein Mensch sitzt, und gehe beim Gegenüber immer von besten Absichten aus.

Comment: Fast wieder lustig.

Answer (score -9):

Dafür müsste *Jacke* zu einer diversen Menge ungesichter Wörter gestellt werden, ebenso der Bauername, der im Hinblick auf das Textil zumindest vergleichsweise durch *burlap* gestützt wird, d.i. im Ansatz *bur-* "Bauer". Dahingehend kann man vorraussetzen, dass *wig, Wickel* (bzw. *wicked*) über die gängigen Lautwandel hinaus, die etwa durch *war* > *guerre* vorausgesetzt sind, im Soziolekt weiter zu *j* abgeschliffen wie es den nordischen Sprachenverwandten eher entsprechen würde.

Was insoweit für den German stack auch relevant ist, all die Weil dieser Lautwandel im kontinentalen Westgermanisch nicht weniger wahrscheinlich ist. Da steht auch *aiw wie unter anderem in *je-* zum Vergleich an.

Interessant wird es erst, wenn Satemisierung erforderlich wird um *Hose* als ureins mit dergleichen zu erklären, während h für j depalatalisiert bzw. velarisiert schon klar geht: sieh auch uvular *Rock*, Cynonym *Rocky*, daneben fricative *Frack* und gänzlich verrückt *Perrücke*, *perrywig*.